# Passing variable by value has the same result as passing it by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, lvalue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        vector <int> arr {12,13,14,15,16};
        for (auto & x: arr)
        {
                ++x;
                cout << x << " ";
        }

return 0;
}
```

VS

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        vector <int> arr {12,13,14,15,16};
        for (auto x: arr)
        {
                ++x;
                cout << x << " ";
        }

return 0;
}
```

The output remains the same and we get each value in the vector incrementing by 1. But my text book says this.
[Text Book Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyKtx.png)
When my textbooks says "x assumes a copy of each value in the vector" what does that mean?

Here is the code output in a screen shot
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYY8J.png)
The first output being with &
The second output without &

Comment: Print the vector again after that loop.

Comment: It isn't needed unless you desire is to leave a wake of incremented values in your vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The output remains the same

If you remove the reference (`&`) you are only passing the value of `x` not `x` itself, so if you have code to change `x` in any way you would need to pass it with reference like you do in the first sample, otherwise you are only changing a local variable, not the original one.

The printed values are the same because in the first example you are incrementing the variable and printing it, in the second sample you are printing the local variable (witch is just a copy) but is also being incremented.

So if you print the vector againg you will see that the version without reference did not change it. As you can see [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KweBt6KVgFAsqXAX)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the elements of your vector (incrementing them by one), hence if you passed the vector elements by value, the loop would use copys of your vector elements not your elelments themselves.

Hence you must use references to your vector elements.

You can make sure of that by using the hint in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not optimal to understand the underlying behavior, try with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void reference()
{
    cout << "reference" << endl;
    vector <int> arr {12,13,14,15,16};
  for (auto& x: arr)
    ++x;
  for (const auto& x : arr)
    cout << x << endl;
}

void value()
{
  cout << "value" << endl;
  vector <int> arr {12,13,14,15,16};
  for (auto x: arr)
    ++x;
  for (const auto& x : arr)
    cout << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
  value();
  reference();
  return 0;
}
```

Now the output will be:

```
value
12
13
14
15
16
reference
13
14
15
16
17
```

As you can see, in the reference case, the values inside the vectors are directly modified, this because you are looping on the `vector` by using references so that the `x` local to the loop is a reference to the actual value inside the `vector` (and not a copy, which is what happens by value).

So any modification is reflected on the original element.

Answer (score 1):

The point about is treating the value of vector by reference and by value.
Below different type of handling the values:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

When it's item value catch by value:

(auto x: arr) then extra copy is created and then we use it in for-loop.

When it's value catch by reference:

(auto &x: arr) the copy is not generated instead the vector item address is taken and the value is used in for-loop. So, the actual vector items/elements are changed in this case.